# How get image from POST?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with an API for mobile devices which allow the user to post image.
Where I'm receiving POST variables I'm using this:

```
 public function endTimesAction()
 {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $arrivalTime = $request->request->get('arrivalTime', 0);
 }
```

How can I get the image from post and save it somewhere on my server?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: How *exactly* are the images being sent to your server?

Comment: Something like this:
http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Yeah I know there is sample php code, but I want to know how do this in Controller and $request variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to create a [form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) add a [file field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html) Then handle the request on the form and save the file.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

public function handleFileUploadAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('')
        //Using the createNamedBuilder on the form factory service will remove the form[] wrapper around the field names
        ->add('uploaded_file','file')
        ->getForm();
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid()){
            $file = $form['uploaded_file']->getData()->move($dir, $someNewFilename);
        }
    }
}
```

From the article you linked it looks like the app is going to post the data to the path using the property name `uploaded_file`. Even though you arent technically using an html form view there is still a "form" being submitted to your web app which is why you will use symfony forms to handle the submission.

Comment: your solution is great, but this will be api for mobile app, so there won't be any form, I will do that like it's here: http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

So I'm going to put this image in request

Comment: Even if there is no html form you will still use one in the controller to handle the post request. From that article it looks like the field name they are posting it under is `uploaded_file`. Try it with that